# Why was this class instantiated inside itself?

Tags: c#

Please help me understand this code. Is this like an enumeration with objects instead of values? Is there are term or pattern that explains this process?

```
public class State
{
    private State(String value)
    {
        Value = value; 
    }

    public String Value { get; set; }

    public static State Open => new State("Open");

    public static State Closed => new State("Closed");

    public static State YourOpen => new State("YourOpen");

    public static State YourClosed => new State("YourClosed");
}
```

Comment: reminds me of `System.Drawing.Color.Black`

Comment: The real question is "why isn't `Value` immutable?"

Comment: This looks like perfectly reasonable code to me.  This is NOT a singleton, but this methodology is used in the singleton pattern.

Comment: its state pattern....

Comment: It's clear, You're not allowed to create your own instances of this class, (Hence the private constructor), But chose from the defined Ones, pretty much like an enum, with a complex type, since the enums are basically ints.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it's [**state pattern**](http://www.dofactory.com/net/state-design-pattern) or [**State Pattern in C#**](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/62825/State-Pattern-in-C) implementation, but not created child classes , instead created method in class itself

In code given by you, each method change state and return instance of changed state. form `Open>>close >>your open >> your close`

[image]

or

[image]

Answer (score 3):

It seems to be a class that:

1. allows to create instances with custom status values (not publicly accessible!)
2. provides instances of itself with pre-defined values

I had overlooked the private constructor. As @jacob-krall pointed out the `typesafe enum` (coming from older Java) seems to suit best.

Answer (score 3):

I think this is an example of a [**typesafe enum**](http://www.javacamp.org/designPattern/enum.html), which defines a finite list of options for a type.